# How to allow only specific alphabets in a Textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox

can I make my text box to allow only L & P for the starting two letters that is entered by a user..  example: LP12345678901. I hope the example makes the question specific...

I tried this
`if(myTextBox.Text.StartsWith("LP"))`

I tried regex too... but we cant be specific in alphabets right?

Comment: so it did'nt worked?

Comment: except starting two letters , others will be numbers ??

Comment: I dont know why I got -1.. any way thanks.. plz try to help.. Im new to C# and programming

Comment: @EhsanSajjad s didnt work.. I used in Validating..

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi s anik.. u r right.

Comment: numbers means only integer value ??

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi yup Anik.. same as the example.. exactly same

Comment: LP is case sensitive ?? like no diff between lp and LP ?? or lp must be uppercase

Comment: Simply use   Regex.IsMatch("Your text to validate", @"^[L,P]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    private void myTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
         if (myTextBox.Text.Length == 2)
          { 
                 if (myTextBox.Text.StartsWith("LP"))
                 {
                    //yourcode
                 }
                 else
                 {
                         myTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                 }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
function Valid() {
        var re = "^[LP][0-9]{11}$";
        var str = document.getElementById("txtTSection").value;
        var myArray = str.match(re);
        if (myArray == null) {
            alert("Incorrect Format");
            $("#txtTSection").css("border-color", "red");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#txtTSection').css('border-color', '');
        }
    }

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTSection" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TabIndex="1" MaxLength="13" onfocusout="Valid()" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a technical solution, but rather an UX suggestion:

If I always have to enter "LP" as the first letters and I'm not allowed to enter different letters or numbers, *then don't make me enter them every time*. You already decided that "LP" *are* the first two letters. There is no point in me typing it again. I cannot gain anything good from it. Even if I'm perfect entering it, the best result I can achieve is "no error message".

If your first two letters have to be "LP" then put "LP" as a label before the textbox and make the user only enter the digits. When you are working with what the user entered, prefix it with "LP".

Comment: Thanks ... I thought of it too.. Ill do that.. But the customer wanted it to be a error message if there is no LP at first two letters.. thats y I posted the question.. I think I should convince him now.. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ValidateSerNo(string ser)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ser))
        {
            if (ser.Trim().Length == 11)
            {
                if (ser.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(0, 2) == "LP")
                {
                    if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(ser.Substring(2, 9)))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((BattVoltMmnt.ValidateSerNo(txtbox_Serialno.Text.Trim().ToUpper()) == false))
        { MessageBox.Show("Enter correct serial number"); 

        }
     }
```